# Scanner file not found exception, but file does exist

Tags: java, netbeans

I keep getting the error below

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - unreported exception java.io.FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
```

The relevant extracts from my code are below. I feel as though I've tried everything, but I'm probably missing something simple. At first I had my text file in the default package section of Netbeans, but the code below to print working directory showed the Netbeans project folder in Documents so I have copied telnos.txt to there, still says file not found.

I have even tried including the full file path, same problem.

```
 private final String sourceName = "telnos.txt"; 

    public void loadData (String sourceName){
        String workingDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
        System.out.println("Current working directory : " + workingDir);
        Scanner read = new Scanner(new File(sourceName));//.useDelimiter("\\Z");
        int i = 1;
        String name = null;
        String telno = null;
        while (read.hasNextLine()) {
            if(i%2 != 0)
                name = read.nextLine();
            else {
                telno = read.nextLine(); 
            add(name, telno);
            }
            i++;
        }

}
```

Comment: How about wrapping your file finding code in a `try/catch` block?

Comment: your error is because of a missing try-catch or throws. either add a try-catch(FileNotFounfException fe) or add a throws FileNotFoundException to the method.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the location of your file. Instead, take a look at this link: [http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner(java.io.File)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29)

Because `new Scanner(new File(sourceName))` has the potential to throw a `FileNotFoundException`, you need to handle the exception, by either catching it here, or throwing it back to the calling method. Because this function doesn't appear to be at the bottom of your call stack, I strongly recommend throwing it back, by changing

```
public void loadData (String sourceName)
```

to

```
public void loadData (String sourceName) throws FileNotFoundException
```

Comment: I have added throws FileNotFoundException but the results are still the same.

'loadData(String) in ArrayPhoneDirectory cannot implement loadData(String) in PhoneDirectory
  overridden method does not throw FileNotFoundException'

Comment: Is the error occurring at the same line in the file? When you add `throws FileNotFoundException`, you're basically telling the function that called this one to deal with the exception. So you'll actually need to add `throws FileNotFoundException` to the function calling `loadData()`, then add to the function that called that one, etc., until you get all the way back to `main()` (and you'll have to add it there too).